# Are all Windows services started before scanning for connected devices?

Tags: windows, service, usb, boot, peripherals

I am writing a WCF service hosted by a Windows service that is responsible for detecting USB devices being connected/disconnected.
Now, in order for this to work I need to understand the Windows boot sequence. Will Windows always start all its services (including mine) before it starts scanning for connected devices?
I need to make sure my service is started first or my list of detected devices will be wrong after rebooting Windows.

Comment: If you register for (arrival) notifications then scan for existing devices does it really matter how Windows behaves thereafter?

Comment: I am not scanning for what is connecting, I am detecting what gets plugged or unplugged.